# ListView selector changes whole listview not the row

Tags: android-listview, android-selector

I've read loads of articles here on listview selectors but I just can't get it to work. When I press a row in my listview the entire listview and not the selected item changes colour. I'm using a Listview fragment and a custom row.

Firstly, my custom row starts like this, the style sets my default background colour and other things to what I want Inside here are just some views. As seen in the left hand picture.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/darkBackdropList"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Next, I have a selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item 
  android:state_pressed="true" 
  android:drawable="@drawable/selected"/> 
</selector>
```

drawable/selected is just a light grey/blue color:

```
<drawable name="selected">#8FBDAB</drawable>
```

In my fragment I do this:

```
public class GuideListFragment extends ListFragment {
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.darklistselector);
}
}
```

When my listview is displayed it all looks fine. But when I select a single row the listview that covers the whole activity changes colour to the 'darklistselector'.

I tried setting this as the custom row background but it just went even more bizarre changing the whole screen between black, grey/blue and white.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault, however in case anyone does the same thing as me. Basically I had to remove my style and change it to:

```
android:background="@drawable/darklistselector"
```

then add a new selector for not pressed:

```
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected"/> 
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/standard"/>
```

With selected being the row highlight and standard being the normal background my style used to be.